# Validar valor request con Laravel

Tags: laravel, select, radiobutton

Tengo un problema con dos campos que hacen la misma funcionalidad pero uno es un RADIO BUTTON y el otro un SELECT. El Radio funciona en pantallas grandes y el select en celulares.

Se ven así: **(los name son distintos)**

```
     @foreach($categorias as $categoria) 
        <input type="radio" id="{{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}" name="rb-categoria" 
        value="{{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}"
        {{ ($categoria->nombre_categoria == 'Alquiler') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                                        
       <label for="{{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}">
          <span class="px-3 m-1 st-btn text-white lead">
          {{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}
          </span>
       </label>

     @endforeach
```

Y el select:

```
 <select class="custom-select st-input" name="rb-categoriaCEL">
        @foreach($categorias as $categoria) 
         <option value="{{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}">{{ $categoria->nombre_categoria }}</option>
        @endforeach
   </select>
```

Ahora no puedo distinguir cuando el usuario uso uno o el otro.

Hay alguna forma de saber si accedió por celular ?

Intente hacer lo siguiente, pero **rb-categoria** está seleccionado por default entonces siempre recibo la variable seleccionada.

```
if(($request->get('rb-categoria') != '') || ($request->get('rb-categoria') != null)){
        
        dd($categoria = $request->get('rb-categoria'));

    }

    if( ($request->get('rb-categoriaCEL') != '') || ($request->get('rb-categoriaCEL') != null))
    {
        
        dd($categoria = $request->get('rb-categoriaCEL'));

    }
```

**EDICIÓN**

Probé esta opción y veo que el problema también persiste. Siempre entra en el primer IF.

```
if( ($request->get('rb-categoriaCEL') != '') && ($request->get('rb-categoriaCEL') != null))
    {
        dd('CELULAR');
        // $categoria = $request->get('rb-categoriaCEL');

    }else{

        dd('ESCRITORIO');
        // $categoria = $request->get('rb-categoria');
    }
```

Comment: No por que rb-categoria tiene esta opción por default $categoria->nombre_categoria == 'Alquiler') ? 'checked' : ''  por lo tanto me viene como si estuviera seleccionada en pantallas grandes

Comment: La primera condición se cumple siempre por lo que necesito que si es desde un celular eso no suceda.

Comment: Agregué una prueba en el código y siempre entra en el IF. Está bien ese if?

Answer (score 1):

Los dos campos me llegaban con el valor por default por lo tanto nunca eran ni nulos ni vacíos.

Al select le agregue un valor vacío.

```
<option value="">Seleccionar operación</option>
```

¡Muchas gracias!